Using a list based fact inside a template produces error: `mapping values are not allowed in this context in "<unicode string>"`
I'm using the following fact:
- name: Set server ips fact
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    k3s_server_ips: "{{ k3s_server_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) }}"
  when: ansible_host in k3s_server_hosts

This produces:
ok: [apollo] => changed=false
  ansible_facts:
    k3s_server_ips:
    - 192.168.4.2
    - 192.168.4.3
    - 192.168.4.4

When I use the defined fact inside a Jinja2 Template:
kubeProxy:
  endpoints: '{{ k3s_server_ips }}'

The following error is displayed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 526, in _execute
    self._task.post_validate(templar=templar)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/playbook/task.py", line 290, in post_validate
    super(Task, self).post_validate(templar)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/playbook/base.py", line 543, in post_validate
    value = method(attribute, getattr(self, name), templar)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/playbook/task.py", line 298, in _post_validate_args
    args = templar.template(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 791, in template
    d[k] = self.template(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 764, in template
    result = self.do_template(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 1010, in do_template
    res = myenv.concat(rf)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/template/native_helpers.py", line 43, in ansible_eval_concat
    head = list(islice(nodes, 2))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<template>", line 18, in root
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/template/__init__.py", line 295, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py", line 221, in from_yaml
    return yaml_load(text_type(to_text(data, errors='surrogate_or_strict')))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 81, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/9.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 49, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 673, in yaml._yaml.CParser.get_single_node
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 687, in yaml._yaml.CParser._compose_document
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 731, in yaml._yaml.CParser._compose_node
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 845, in yaml._yaml.CParser._compose_mapping_node
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 731, in yaml._yaml.CParser._compose_node
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 847, in yaml._yaml.CParser._compose_mapping_node
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 860, in yaml._yaml.CParser._parse_next_event
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed in this context
  in "<unicode string>", line 26, column 68
fatal: [apollo]: FAILED! => changed=false

This happens only when I use the fact inside the template, if I use k3s_server_ips inside a task, there are no issues.
As workaround, I tried:
kubeProxy:
  endpoints:
{% for ip in k3s_server_ips %}
    - {{ ip }}
{% endfor %}

Which fixes the issue. I'm wondering if there is a better implementation.

For me it looks like that there are several different syntax errors (kind of) and or logic errors. Furthermore your question is missing several important information and playbook parts about how do you like to use that all, as well important debug output. You may have a look into How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Even if this seems to be a strange Use Case for me in my opinion, please find a working minimal reproducible example as answer.

The error message
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed in this contextvin "<unicode string>"

indicates syntax and or indention errors within your created YAML structure.
For a Jinja2 Template called templates/my_list.j2 as input and with content of
kubeProxy:
  endpoints:
    {{ k3s_server_ips | to_nice_yaml(indent=4) | trim | indent(4) }}
  as_well:
{% for ip in k3s_server_ips %}
    - {{ ip }}
{% endfor %}

processing with a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    k3s_server_ips:
      - 192.168.4.2
      - 192.168.4.3
      - 192.168.4.4

  tasks:

  - template:
      src: templates/my_list.j2
      dest: kubeProxy.endpoints.yml

  - name: "Set from template"
    set_fact:
      my_list: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.template', 'templates/my_list.j2') }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ my_list | from_yaml }}"

will result into an output of
TASK [debug] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    kubeProxy:
      as_well:
      - 192.168.4.2
      - 192.168.4.3
      - 192.168.4.4
      endpoints:
      - 192.168.4.2
      - 192.168.4.3
      - 192.168.4.4

as well a file written, called kubeProxy.endpoints.yml with content of
kubeProxy:
  endpoints:
    - 192.168.4.2
    - 192.168.4.3
    - 192.168.4.4
  as_well:
    - 192.168.4.2
    - 192.168.4.3
    - 192.168.4.4

Thanks To / Similar Q&A

Variable as a YAML tree. How to save indent?
Ansible: How to set_fact from Template- / YAML-file?



"I'm wondering if there is a better implementation."

Probably yes, by not using set_fact, respective avoiding intermediate facts. Just take the shortcut and not the detour via the playbook by directly generating the k3s_server_ips list within the Jinja2 Template.

Thank you for the useful information, I wanted to make sure the for ip in k3s_server_ips loop is the correct approach in my case.
